# Why are Django debugging errors suppressed by uWSGI?

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I am running a nginx  and uWSGI setup with Django but the errors are no longer shown in Django even though debugging is enabled: `DEBUG = True`. All errors that occur are saved in the `uWSGI` log file instead. How can i enable Django to show them again?

nginx.conf:

```
server {
        access_log              /var/www/servers/myserver/development/logs/nginx_access.log;
        error_log               /var/www/servers/myserver/development/logs/nginx_error.log warn;
        server_name             localhost
        listen                  [::]:80;
        charset                 utf-8;

        client_max_body_size    75M;

        location / {
                uwsgi_pass      unix:/var/www/servers/myserver/development/sockets/myserver-dev.sock;
                include         /var/www/servers/myserver/development/configs/uwsgi_params;
                deny            all;
        }

        location /static {
                autoindex       on;
                alias           /var/www/servers/myserver/development/static;
        }

        location /media {
                autoindex       on;
                alias           /var/www/servers/myserver/development/media;
        }
}
```

uwsgi.conf:

```
[uwsgi]
;enable master process manager
master = true

;spawn 2 uWSGI worker processes
workers = 2

;unix socket (referenced in nginx configuration)
socket = /var/www/servers/myserver/development/sockets/myserver-dev.sock

# set mode of created UNIX socket
chmod-socket = 666

# place timestamps into log
log-date = true

# user identifier of uWSGI processes
uid = www-data
# group identifier of uWSGI processes
gid = www-data

; number of worker processes
;processes = 2
;vacuum = true

; project-level logging to the logs/ folder
;logto = /var/www/servers/myserver/development/logs/uwsgi.log


; django >= 1.4 project
chdir = /var/www/servers/myserver/development/webapp
wsgi-file = /var/www/servers/myserver/development/webapp/webapp/wsgi.py

;enable-threads = true

virtualenv = /var/www/servers/myserver/development/env
vacuum = true
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=webapp.settings
pidfile = /var/www/servers/myserver/development/logs/myserver-dev.pid
;harakiri = 20 # respawn processes taking more than 20 seconds
;max-requests = 5000 # respawn processes after serving 5000 requests
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try double checking that `DEBUG == True` is actually correct. I suspect it's not. You could do this in one of your views with the following code.

```
## inside a view function
from django.conf import settings
raise Exception('Value of DEBUG is %s' % (settings.DEBUG,))
```

Restart uWSGI and try visiting that view. You should see if your supposition is correct immediately.

Comment: I ran the project without uWSGI (runserver) where debugging works like a charm. Even with this exception i still just get a `502 Bad Gateway` error from nginx.

Comment: Yup, what is the error message that you are getting in the uwsgi logs?  What is the value of DEBUG?

Comment: I tried to insert the exception, but it does not appear in the log. The error message i get in the log is a missing mysql library, very common error.

Comment: exactly! I need to use `runserver` in order to debug, its a bit of a mess while developing and testing nginx performance..

Comment: There is nothing particular about uWSGI that changes this behaviour. I use uWSGI with debug enabled all the time. So it's something in your settings.

Comment: If i remove the database configuration which triggers the error and use the exception you recommended i do infact get the debug on the page `Value of DEBUG is True`, but why does it suppress a library error? When i use `runserver` it shows the error without any problems. Is it a different level of error?

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing now, with a urlconf error. Still nothing shows up..

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured log handlers in your application? I'm not really familiar with Django anymore but in Flask having debug=True with uwsgi will actually strip all your logging handlers. Instead you need to set up handlers and have debug=False.

I would have suspected that general error handling won't work within uwsgi in the same way as with runserver - http://librelist.com/browser/flask/2011/10/19/debug-when-deploy-in-uwsgi/#7be089baf631971dfb73a5a7b79e2248